# Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid formed by rotating the region enclosed by the curves $y=(e^ x) + 2$, $y=0$ , $x=0$, and $x=0.7$ about the $x$-axis

I set up the equations as follows using the washer method. I'm not sure if I'm setting it up right or using the correct method.

$$\int_0^{0.7} \pi (e^x+2)^2dx$$

Comment: The setup is correct. To finish, expand $(e^x+2)^2$ and integrate.

Comment: Note you can pull the $\pi$ out of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is correct.
$$\begin{align*}
A & = \pi \int_0^{0.7} (e^x + 2)^2\ dx = \pi \left( \int_0^{0.7} e^{2x}\ dx + 4 \int_0^{0.7} e^x\ dx + 4\cdot0.7 \right)\\
& = \pi \left( \frac12 \int_0^{1.4} e^x\ dx + 4 \int_0^{0.7} e^x\ dx + 2.8\right)\\
& = \pi \left( \frac12 (e^{1.4}-1) + 4(e^{0.7}-1) + 2.8 \right) \\
& \approx 26.3347\ldots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Not sure your answer is correct. Note $e^0\ne0$.

Comment: @JohnMolokach $e^0 = 1$ by definition...

Comment: Sorry, edited...

Comment: It might be me, but are you sure you can make the simplification of taking $e^{2x}$ out to the range over which you're integrating?  As if you leave it in and integrate, it integrates to $e^2x^2$ so you wouldn't simply be evaluating $e^x$ between $0$ and $1.4$. I'm not entirely sure that gives the same answer.

Comment: @RobertFrost That‘s a substitution, yielding the factor of $1/2$

Comment: Ok; I scanned the answers as the question got bumped to the home page, and I just thought I'd ask - but you will know better than me. I last did calculus 30 years ago!

Comment: @RobertFrost Note that normal integration yields $\frac12 e^{2x}$ and not $e^2x^2$, so the result is easily seen to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup was all correct. However, you can conveniently integrate with symbols and get on with integration to go to numerical work in the last stages of calculation by  plugging in constants. Also, bring out constants to LHS at the earliest, else that keeps tagging on till the end.

$$\begin{align*}
A/\pi & =  \int_0^{a} (e^x + c)^2\ dx = \int_0^{a} e^{2x}\ dx + 2c \int_0^{a} e^x\ dx + c^2 a\\
& = \frac12 ( e^{2a}-1) + 2c(e^{a}-1)\  + ac^2.\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

As this just got bumped from the homepage and @AlexR' answer is not correct, here the correct answer

\begin{align*}
A & = \pi \int_0^{0.7} (e^x + 2)^2\ dx = \pi \left( \int_0^{0.7} e^{2x}\ dx + 4 \int_0^{0.7} e^x\ dx + 4\int_0^{0.7}dx\right)\\
& = \pi \left( \int_0^{0.7} e^{2x}\ dx + 4 \int_0^{0.7} e^x\ dx + 4\cdot0.7 \right)\\
& = \pi \left( \frac12 \int_0^{1.4} e^x\ dx + 4\int_0^{0.7} e^x\ dx + 2.8\right)\qquad \qquad(u=2x,du=2dx)\\
& = \pi \left( \frac12 \left(e^{1.4}-e^0\right) + 4\left(e^{0.7}-e^0\right) + 2.8 \right) \\
& \approx 26.3347\ldots
\end{align*}